# Pandas: Get label for value in Series Object

Tags: python, pandas, series

How is it possible to retrieve the labe of a particular value in a pandas Series object:

For example:

```
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
s = Series (arange(5) * 4 , labels)
```

Which produces the Series:

```
a     0
b     4
c     8
d    12
e    16
dtype: int64
```

How is it possible to get the label of value '12'? Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get the subseries by:

```
In [90]: s[s==12]
Out[90]: 
d    12
dtype: int64
```

Moreover, you can get those labels by

```
In [91]: s[s==12].index
Out[91]: Index([d], dtype=object)
```